# Firebase Update Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, memory-leaks

I have a listener attached to a Firebase key that takes changes, runs it through processing on my end, and then updates a Firebase key with the result. The code would look like this:

```
db.child(key).on('child_added', (snap) => {
  processing(snap.val())
    .then([snapKey, obj] => db.child(snapKey).update(obj))
});
```

However, when I've noticed that everytime update is called on the Firebase key, the memory usage leaks several megabytes, which is unacceptable.

This is what my code looks like when I use a probe from `memwatch-next`:

```
db.child(key).on('child_added', (snap) => {
  processing(snap.val())
    .then([snapKey, firebaseObj]) => {
      return new Promise((res) => {
        hd = new memwatch.HeapDiff();
        db.child(key).child(snapKey).update(firebaseObj, () => {
          res(hd);
        })
      })
    })
    .then((hd) => {
      console.log(hd.end());
    })
});
```

This is are several iterations of what the `console.log(hd.end())` line returns when I run the code (each iteration as in each child that is added):

```
{ before: { nodes: 146168, size_bytes: 17594735, size: '16.78 mb' },
  after: { nodes: 176255, size_bytes: 19080111, size: '18.2 mb' },
  change: 
  { size_bytes: 1485376,
    size: '1.42 mb',
    freed_nodes: 5187,
    allocated_nodes: 35274,
    details: 
    [ [Object],
      ...
      [Object] ] } }

{ before: { nodes: 178862, size_bytes: 19198176, size: '18.31 mb' },
  after: { nodes: 212089, size_bytes: 20877626, size: '19.91 mb' },
  change: 
  { size_bytes: 1679450,
    size: '1.6 mb',
    freed_nodes: 1471,
    allocated_nodes: 34699,
    details: 
     [ [Object],
       ...
       [Object] ] } }

{ before: { nodes: 214254, size_bytes: 20919620, size: '19.95 mb' },
  after: { nodes: 247320, size_bytes: 22549300, size: '21.5 mb' },
  change: 
   { size_bytes: 1629680,
     size: '1.55 mb',
     freed_nodes: 1404,
     allocated_nodes: 34471,
     details: 
      [ [Object],
        ...
    [Object] ] } }

{ before: { nodes: 249507, size_bytes: 22614374, size: '21.57 mb' },
  after: { nodes: 282578, size_bytes: 24219130, size: '23.1 mb' },
  change: 
   { size_bytes: 1604756,
     size: '1.53 mb',
     freed_nodes: 1390,
     allocated_nodes: 34462,
     details: 
      [ [Object],
        ...
        [Object] ] } }

{ before: { nodes: 284930, size_bytes: 24329463, size: '23.2 mb' },
  after: { nodes: 317934, size_bytes: 25917780, size: '24.72 mb' },
  change: 
   { size_bytes: 1588317,
     size: '1.51 mb',
     freed_nodes: 1400,
     allocated_nodes: 34405,
     details: 
      [ [Object],
        ...
        [Object] ] } }
```

As a result of this leak, when running my node app, I run into this error:

```
Error: spawn ENOMEM
at _errnoException (util.js:999:13)
at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:340:11)
at exports.spawn (child_process.js:499:9)
at Object.exports.fork (child_process.js:100:10)
at rateLimit (/home/deploy/amNewBack/releases/20180104233801/index.js:118:33)
at ChildProcess.n.on 
(/home/deploy/amNewBack/releases/20180104233801/index.js:143:15)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
at emit (internal/child_process.js:790:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
FATAL ERROR: Committing semi space failed. Allocation failed - process out of         
memory
1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
2: 0x11ef43c [/usr/local/bin/node]
3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) 
[/usr/local/bin/node]
5: 
v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, 
v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
6: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, 
v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) 
[/usr/local/bin/node]
7: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, 
v8::internal::PretenureFlag) 
[/usr/local/bin/node]
8: v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::internal::Vector<char const>, 
 v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
9: v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::NewStringType, int) 
 [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: node::StringBytes::Encode(v8::Isolate*, char const*, unsigned long, 
 node::encoding, v8::Local<v8::Value>*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x120b762 [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)
 (v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0xb7c08c [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**,     
 v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
15: 0x326bb34842fd
FATAL ERROR: Deoptimizer::EnsureCodeForDeoptimizationEntry Allocation failed -     
 process out of memory
1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
2: 0x11ef43c [/usr/local/bin/node]
3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) 
 [/usr/local/bin/node]
5:v8::internal::Deoptimizer::EnsureCodeForDeoptimizationEntry
(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Deoptimizer::BailoutType, int) 
[/usr/local/bin/node]
6: v8::internal::Deoptimizer::EnsureCodeForMaxDeoptimizationEntries
(v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
7: v8::internal::compiler::PipelineCompilationJob::PrepareJobImpl() 
[/usr/local/bin/node]
8: v8::internal::CompilationJob::PrepareJob() [/usr/local/bin/node]
9: 0xd9a7af [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::Compiler::CompileOptimized
(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, 
v8::internal::ConcurrencyMode) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::Runtime_CompileOptimized_Concurrent(int, 
v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x1e20022042fd
```

The error itself is caused when my node process forks during the `processing()`, however, from the results of `memwatch-next`, the loss of memory appears during the Firebase update step. Is this a present bug in Firebase?

Comment: If it leaks several MB on every invocation, certainly you run out of memory if it's invocated many times.  Is that the case?

Comment: Yes that is the case. the observer will be executing thousands of times over the course of several hours, and every time a new snapshot is observed, you can expect a Firebase update to occur (after some processing of course).

Comment: So you're observing running out of memory?

Comment: Yes my app is running out of memory.

Comment: What's the error messages when your app crashes?  I'm not sure how you can be certain this is because of Firebase.  FYI there are no open issues regarding memory problems for the node SDK.  If you are able to prove, using an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), that the SDK leaks, then please file a bug report. https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, I added the error message, as well as the `memwatch-next` logging that shows the leaking of memory. I just wanted to run this by you to see if my logic makes sense or if you have any last comments before I create an independent MCVE. Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably want to show the amount of memory use after *every* child you're processing, not just one of them.  Show that there is a pattern that repeats over time, not a one time loss.

Comment: I added the logs for 5 consecutive children that show the growth in memory. On my own computer, I ran it for about another 100 children and the memory growth shows no signs of abating.

Comment: Have you considered that maybe kicking off async work inside child_added could possibly create **a lot** of concurrent processing tasks that don't wait for each other to complete?  I suspect your child_added callback is not really synchronous, and they're piling up with each child.

Comment: That's a good point. However, I tried that through 2 ways and the memory still appears to be leaking:
1) I limited my frontend to only add one child at a time (it would add one child, wait for a Firebase update from my processing code, and then add another child, etc)
2) I used semaphores to restrict the amount of child nodes going through processing to one at a time.
Through both methods, the memory continues to leak at the same amounts as before.

Comment: File a bug with an MCVE.  Make sure that it's easy to reproduce.